# Create string of n characters without loop

Tags: javascript, string

In Python I can use:

```
s = "x" * 10
xxxxxxxxxx
```

How in JavaScript, do I create a string n characters long without a loop?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use `String.repeat`

```
"x".repeat(10);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat

On old browsers you could do

```
new Array(10).join('x')
```

Comment: Excellent answer, sadly it doesn't work with ExtendScript (ESTK 3.8), which is what I'm using  :(

Comment: Please note that you need to do Array(len + 1).join(chr) in order to get the desired number of characters. (Join adds a character between each item in the array, so it will add n-1 characters).

Answer (score 1):

Use `repeat` method.

```
'x'.repeat(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new Array(11).join('x')
```

For 10 `x` you need `11` in new Array so that 10th x is visible.